# Issue in kNN regression using R?

Tags: r, regression, knn, non-linear-regression

I am trying to do prediction using `kNN` regression in R. I have two variable (X,Y) in excel table format (total 800 data-sets in each variable). My aim is to predict the value of `Y` (present in Test table) So for that I have written code in R as follows,

```
Table <-read.csv("Table.csv")
Y <-Table[1,];X <-Table[2,];
data_norm<-function(x){((x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x)))}
Table_norm<-as.data.frame(laaply(Table),data_norm)
Train<-Table(1:30)
Test<-Table(31:49)
library(class)
ypred= <-knn(TRain,Test,Test[1:30,1],k=20)
```

I have attached the sample of data in Table format attached [here](http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/698100/Table.xlsx)[3](https://www.mediafire.com/myaccount/email_validation.php?u=a5bec8ba4c86b773569dcde48d73fc0b93a3e810c22dfe09f9c181b5f25ca8781564b4a7f3d3344f01b8f28071c72f7e11ebcfb6c053f1269eed24b52d659b8d&p=0439)

While doing so I am getting the following error, 'Error in laaply(Table) : could not find function "laaply"
'. The information about `laaply` is [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.1/topics/lapply).

I want to use above Table 1st 3o data points for training the kNN model and then rest of data points to predict the value of Y for given x

I did all search and try to solve such problem but not able to solve this problem.

Comment: Or even `lapply`? Without a working example it is hard to say for certain, but it seems to be just a simple typo giving you the error.

Comment: @MarcoSandri what is `laply`?

Comment: No it is laaply not laply. See this https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.1/topics/lapply

Comment: Your question does not contain a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCVE). This makes it hard to understand and answer your question. Please share relevant code, a small excerpt of your data and the expected outcome. You can find detailed information on how to create a goo MCVE for R [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: I added the sample of data sets and modified as per your suggestion please have a look